# Openrefine add Counter to value

Tags: openrefine

I'm using a text facet to get only rows that include a certain value. With the resulting rows I'd like to fill down a column with values from another column. This is how I'm doing:

```
cells["Auto_Objektkennung"].value
```

How could I add a continuing number to every value starting with 0?

Pseudo Code:

```
cells["Auto_Objektkennung"].value + '-' + COUNTER+1
```

Unfortunately, the row index does not help as due to the text facet I'm not starting with one but somewhere around 8000

```
cells["Auto_Objektkennung"].value + '-' + row.record.index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a manual way to achieve this with OpenRefine and GREL without delegating the task to Clojure or Jython.

**Idea:** We can first create records based on a text facet or text filter.
Then we can use `row.record.index` to create the expected "continuing number[s]".

**Recipe:**

1. With your text facet (or filter) active, add a new column named "record_marker".
2. Move the new column "record_marker" to the beginning.
3. Add a new column "counter" using the expression `row.record.index - 1`.
4. Blank down the new "counter" column.
5. You can now use the "counter" column in your expression.

```
if(cells["counter"].value >= 0, cells["Auto_Objektkennung"].value + "-" + cells["counter"].value, "")
```

6. Clean up by deleting the "record_marker" and "counter" columns.